# How to update a column on daily wise

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to update a column adding present value of the column and the new updated value

Example..

If countofcustomer column value is 5 yester  and today if v are getting new updated value for

countofcustomer as 2 then the column should get updated as 7.

Comment: `update table set countofcustomer = countofcustomer + 2`

Comment: @Nikil - There can be random values once 2 or 5 or more so I guess I cant add +2 in query

Comment: `update table set countofcustomer = countofcustomer + (select count(*) from table where added_date = sysdate)`

Comment: Its doubling me the value and getting updated...

Answer (score 1):

```
update table
set value = v.value 
from table t join 
(Select Sum(value),customer
from table
where month(ENDDATETIME) =  month(getdate())    
group by customer
)v
on v.customer = t.customer
```

Comment: @Azar-I'm getting the count on Monthly wise so I should get countofcustomer for this month i.e.,july 1 to 31. The above query gives me the count of previous month too.

Comment: i'm using this condition in where clause "where ENDDATETIME >= DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GetDate()), 0) 
and ENDDATETIME <=DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GetDate()), 30)" but still its not getting updated

Comment: incorrect usage of dateadd function you should have date column in last parameter or it will take like if it is 0 1900:01:01 , if it is 30 1900:01:30 like wise

Comment: Use this datediff(mm,endatetime,getdate()) = 0

Comment: I tried your updated query. And its giving me the aacepted result. Thank you so much. It was really help full

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I correctly understand the question, but maybe trigger could be useful:

[msdn trigger:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms189799.aspx)

You execute an action when an event to a table is raised (like an update).

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
update tbl set countofcustomer=countofcustomer + 2
```